# The best way to conect to my Raspberry Pi Zero W by MAC address?

Tags: raspbian, connection, raspi-config

I want to know the best way to connect my RBP by wifi using the MAC Address.
I currently use `sudo nmap -sn 192.168.0.0/24` and obtain this

```bsh
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.114
Host is up (0.025s latency).
MAC Address: B8:27:EB:50:00:00 (Raspberry Pi Foundation)
```

and after that, I connected to the RBP by SHH
`ssh pi@192.168.0.114`

the problem is that my internet connection is so unstable so, I have to repeat this a lot of times.

Is any way to connect directly by MAC?

**Edit:** Actually I am using [Dataplicity](https://www.dataplicity.com/) 
 for [alternative third-party](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/access-over-Internet/README.md) solutions.

Comment: Hello, have you tried `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` where `raspberrypi` is the hostname of your PiZW courtesy of the Avahi daemon and mDNS? https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ip-address.md

Comment: @RogerJones `raspberrypy.local` is reserved for [link-local addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) from 169.254.0.0/16. The RasPi has a private address so it cannot work.

Comment: @ingo Hmmm, I thought the [.local](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local) addresses were for any private address? Anyway, the question read to me as if the OP was actually asking for a way to SSH to the Pi without having to scan for it's IP address each time.

Comment: @ingo link-local addresses have NOTHING to do with.local; I use .local as my normal addressing mode on my home network.

Comment: @Milliways You are not right. Please read [wikipedia - .local](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local) to understand the context between link-local addresses and the official reserved DNS domain **.local**.

Comment: Thank you @RogerJones! I have been able to connect with  `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local`

Comment: In addition to the [answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/96215/93934) by @Milliways I'd also suggest assigning a static IP address to your Pi *or* reserving one for your Pi at your DHCP server. Depends how much effort you want to put in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not connect by `MAC` - although you could use `MAC` to resolve IP.

**You DO NOT need to know the IP address to connect to your Pi.**
You can just connect to your server by name e.g. `raspberrypi.local` instead of IP address.
(NOTE raspberrypi is the default hostname, and can/should be changed).

You can easily connect from Linux and OS X with `ssh pi@hostname.local` (the default hostname is *raspberrypi*) This should work with popular GUI ssh programs. This is sometimes problematic with some versions of Windows and networks which use .local in a non-standard way. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local)

NOTE .local resolution does not always work e.g. in rsync. The following should resolve IP (and can be included in bash scripts)

```
RemotePi=$(getent hosts hostname.local | awk '{ print $1 }')
```

If you **REALLY** want to know the IP address you can discover it by many means;

`arp raspberrypi.local` on most networks (`arp raspberrypi` may work on some)

e.g.

```
arp archpi.local
archpi.local (10.1.1.20) -- no entry
```

or

```
getent hosts archpi.local | awk '{ print $1 }'
10.1.1.20
```

or

```
ping -c 1 archpi.local
PING archpi.local (10.1.1.20): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.1.1.20: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=4.607 ms
```

Comment: Thanks! I have been able to connect with `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local`

Comment: It's misleading to say that, "You DO NOT need to know the IP address to connect to your Pi." At some level, the IP address must be known. If not by you explicitly, then by the software you are using. And not all systems from which someone may initiate a connection will participate in mDNS/avahi/Bonjour or the other flavors of [zero configuration networking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking) that are in play today.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use IP network connections, then there is no other way to address devices than with ip addresses. This is by design that can be described with the [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) (**O**pen **S**ystems **I**nterconnection model). Network connections are made on [Layer 3: Network Layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#Layer_3:_Network_Layer) using ip addresses. MAC addresses are used on the underlaying [Layer 2: Data Link Layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#Layer_2:_Data_Link_Layer) to recover the ip address from the device by using the **arp** protocol. But it is not used for connections.